# WAMP и 403 ошибка

Tags: apache, windows, wamp

Проблема с WAMP: создал нормально alias, но переход по нему дает 403 ошибку. Все остальные ссылки WAMP работают. В алиасе проставлено "Allow from all". Что это может быть и как это пофиксить?

Comment: Настройки покажите.

Answer (score 1):

1. возможно что нет файла индексного в каталоге.
2. файл .htacess в нем стоят запреты.

Можно попробовать в .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

А так вообще хорошо бы конфиги увидеть.

Что неужели от и до скопипастил с сайта htaccess.net? Просто уж очень больно знакомый код :)

```
<Directory "/">Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViewsAllowOverride AllOrder allow,denyAllow from all</Directory>
```

Смысл писать то чего не знаешь?

Comment: Alias /nemo/ "d:/code/nemo/" <Directory "d:/code/nemo/">    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews    AllowOverride all        Order Deny,AllowAllow from all</Directory>